# Python: \n not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I'm trying to format some data in the code below, but my second `\n` is not recognized, thus I'm not getting a new line for content contained in body.

Any explanation as to why this would happen??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import requests
import datetime
import sys

OAUTH_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
repos = ['my-app']

# List pull request
def list_pr():
    for repo in repos:
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/davanand/%s/pulls' % repo, auth=('token', OAUTH_KEY))
        data = r.json()

        for i in data:
            print i['user']['login'] + '\n' + i['title'] + '\n' + i['body']

list_pr()
```

Comment: Can you please add what you expected as output and what you got instead?

Comment: Are you sure that the indent of your code is correct?

Comment: Maybe you need a '\n' after i['body'], otherwise the code looks ok. Would like to see the raw input and the output to better understand what happens.

Comment: Expected output is user, title and body on separate lines.  I get the new line after user, but not after title which puts body and title on the same line.  I tried different indenting options with no luck and I tried to add \n after body and same results.

Comment: @TrisNefzger `print` adds a newline to the end of output.

Comment: Shouldn't data = r.json() be indented?  I found that 'for i in data' and the subsequent print on the next line need indenting too.

Comment: I've adjust the code as you stated and still the same output...still, no line break after title.

Comment: Show us the print of the json (Atleast one or two elements inside `data`).

Comment: My tests with requests.get().json() shows it extracts json only and not html, so it would not get the html title and body of a web page and trying to print them from json response content should give an error unless of course there actually is such content with those elements which I cannot verify.  However, looking at https://api.github.com/users/davanand and https://api.github.com/repos/davanand/web-code, for examples, shows no user, title or body keys while the latter shows login under owner.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, newlines and all, after substituting my own `OAUTH_KEY` and repo.  Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: It appears that, in your code, sometimes you're indenting with tabs, sometimes with 4 spaces.  It looks like your indents are consistent within the blocks, though, which is why you're not getting an error there.  Have you tried printing without spaces, like `print i['user']['login']+'\n'+i['title']+'\n'+i['body']`?  Not sure if that will change anything, just something to try.  You'll also want to stick with either tabs or spaces for all of your indents.